# Python Seaborn: ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation fmin which has no identity

Tags: python, seaborn

I would like to plot a correlation heatmap in Seaborn with code below:

```
import seaborn as sb
corr = data1.corr()
sb.heatmap(corr, annot=True)
```

for data1 as below:

```
    Column 1    Column 2 Column 3 Column 4 Column 5 Column 6
1   2178        0        0        66       0        1207
2   1042        0        0        60       0        921
3   2096        0        0        112      0        1744
4   1832        0        0        109      0        1718
5   1341        0        0        38       0        889
```

but it caught error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-ab82ce39625d> in <module>
      1 import seaborn as sb
      2 corr = data1.corr()
----> 3 sb.heatmap(corr,  annot=True)

C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_decorators.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     44             )
     45         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 46         return f(**kwargs)
     47     return inner_f
     48 

C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py in heatmap(data, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust, annot, fmt, annot_kws, linewidths, linecolor, cbar, cbar_kws, cbar_ax, square, xticklabels, yticklabels, mask, ax, **kwargs)
    533     """
    534     # Initialize the plotter object
--> 535     plotter = _HeatMapper(data, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust, annot, fmt,
    536                           annot_kws, cbar, cbar_kws, xticklabels,
    537                           yticklabels, mask)

C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py in __init__(self, data, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust, annot, fmt, annot_kws, cbar, cbar_kws, xticklabels, yticklabels, mask)
    153 
    154         # Determine good default values for the colormapping
--> 155         self._determine_cmap_params(plot_data, vmin, vmax,
    156                                     cmap, center, robust)
    157 

C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py in _determine_cmap_params(self, plot_data, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust)
    192                 vmin = np.nanpercentile(calc_data, 2)
    193             else:
--> 194                 vmin = np.nanmin(calc_data)
    195         if vmax is None:
    196             if robust:

<__array_function__ internals> in nanmin(*args, **kwargs)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\lib\nanfunctions.py in nanmin(a, axis, out, keepdims)
    319         # Fast, but not safe for subclasses of ndarray, or object arrays,
    320         # which do not implement isnan (gh-9009), or fmin correctly (gh-8975)
--> 321         res = np.fmin.reduce(a, axis=axis, out=out, **kwargs)
    322         if np.isnan(res).any():
    323             warnings.warn("All-NaN slice encountered", RuntimeWarning,

ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation fmin which has no identity
```

What does the error mean?

---

Edit:

I tried:

```
corr = data1.corr()
plt.subplots(figsize=(20,15))
sns.heatmap(corr,  annot = True, vmin=-1, vmax=1, center= 0)
```

and it returned output:
[image]

Comment: I have run your code and it is displaying correctly. My environment is seaborn 0.11.1 pandas 1.2.5 matplotlib 3.4.2.